# Azure Response Time Monitoring per request with a range

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

Very new to azure application insight,

I want to group all the request with respective duration. For example, I want to put the response time which is in between 0-3 second as "Green/Color", 3-5 second in "Yellow/Color" and greater than 5 should be "Red/Color".

I am using the below Kusto Query language, which need to enhanced

`requests  | where timestamp > ago(2h)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [case function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction) combined with the fact that the request duration is stored in the `duration` field in milliseconds:

```
requests  
| where timestamp > ago(2h)
| extend color = case(duration <= 3000, "Green/Color", 
                       duration <= 5000, "Yellow/Color", 
                       "Red/Color")
| project timestamp, url, resultCode, color, duration
```